# Clearing a text file in PHP

Tags: php, file

I have a text file that ends up with over 500 lines of text each day. I'm setting up a cron job to manually clear the file at the end of the day but I cannot get it to clear. I've looked online and tried the methods below, but nothing seems to clear the text file... (I ran the file on my server and checked the .txt file using Transmit FTP Client to check the text file and the 500+ lines of text were still there.)

```
$handle = fopen ("emails.txt", "w+");
fclose($handle);
```

```
file_put_contents('emails.txt', '');
```

```
$handle = fopen("emails.txt", "w+");
fwrite($handle , '');
fclose($handle);
```

How can I empty this text file using PHP?

Comment: Where is the file located on the server? Do you have permission to write to it?

Comment: The txt file is in the same directory as the php file, and the file has 777 permissions :/

Comment: `w+`  is "open for append". why don't you just `unlink()` the file so it's completely gone? the next time you try to w+ it, it'll be re-created. That or open with `w` only, which is "open for write, clear-out if exists".

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow. Thanks for explaining what you've tried in your post. I've just made a few minor formatting and wording changes. This is still probably going to be tricky to answer -- there's probably some specific detail that's not included in your post that's responsible for this, but it's hard to know what that is. Hopefully somebody will have an helpful insight to share.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This works for me:

```
$f = fopen('emails.txt','r');
$content = file('emails.txt');
array_splice($content, 0, 500);
file_put_contents('emails.txt', $content);
fclose($f);
```

Comment: Oops, I omitted opening the file, try now, I edited my answer.

Answer (score 0):

It looks like you want to truncate your file.

Try with `w`, instead of `w+` http://www.tizag.com/phpT/filetruncate.php

You may also want to check your error logs. If the file isn't writeable by the web / apache user then nothing significant will occur.

Comment: I used: 
    $myFile = "emails.txt";
    $fh = fopen($myFile, 'w');
    fclose($fh);

from the link you posted and still nothing. The txt file has 777 permissions as well, and i dont see anything in error_log

Answer (score 0):

If you have this on a cron task, you may want to use sed instead.  Sed can remove as many lines as you wish from a file.

[Unix Sed Command to Delete lines in file](http://www.folkstalk.com/2013/03/sed-remove-lines-file-unix-examples.html)

`sed '1d' file` removes the first line in a file, while `sed '2,4d' file` would remove lines 2 through 4.

If you do this via cron, be sure to include the full path to your file, from / (root) forward.

Answer (score 0):

Assuming that your script have permissions to write to the text file and that the two files are located in the same directory. I guess that you're not running the script from the same directory, so you could try this :

```
$handle = fopen (__DIR__."/emails.txt", "w");
fclose($handle);
```